# Finding a and b from $a+b/3 = 1$ and $a/2+b/4=3/5$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have two equations of which I need to solve for $a$ and $b$.

$$
a+b/3=1\\
a/2+b/4=3/5
$$
Find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: sorry. eq1: a+b/3=1

Comment: Hint:  The first equation tells us $a =1 -\frac 13 b$.  Substitute that into the second equation and solve for $b$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve a simultaneous equation with 2 variables, one easier way is to multiply any one of the equation by a constant, such that the coefficient of the same variable in the 2 equations becomes the same.

In this example, multiply the second equation by $2$. We get the system
$$a+b/3=1$$
$$a+b/2=3/5$$

Then subtract one equation from another. As one may observe, one of the variable vanishes. This is called **elimination**.

Then one should obtain an equation with one variable left. To be more specific here, an equation in terms of only $b$ is produced. Solving the equation, one can obtain the value of the variable.

By **back substitution**, that is, to plug in the solved value of the variable (Here, $b$ is the solved one.) into any of the equations, the other unknown can finally be solved.

---

A more advanced yet general and equivalent method is to reduce the coefficent matrix of the system into row-echelon form.

Comment: Numbers do not "vanish", they may become  equal to zero

Comment: Has bkmath heard of Cramer's rule

Comment: Of course I did. But I don't think OP would have known Cramer's Rule if he/she doesn't even know how to solve this system.